# Post request throwing antiforgery token error for mvc applications in SSO flow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, csrf, adfs, antiforgerytoken

Post request throwing antiforgery token error for mvc applications in SSO flow , in normal application flow it works for same post method with same code base .

[image]